# padding for weeks outside of the dates in the original data

Tags: r, padr

How can I pad for weeks outside of the dates in the original data?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(x=c("2019-01-02", 
                     "2019-01-02",
                     #"2019-01-03",
                     "2019-01-04",
                     "2019-01-04",
                     "2019-01-04",
                     "2019-01-09",
                     "2019-01-19"),
                 y=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0))

# aggregate by week
df %>% 
  mutate(x = lubridate::ymd(as.character(x))) %>%
  group_by(date = lubridate::floor_date(x, "1 week")) 

# # A tibble: 7 x 3
# # Groups:   date [3]
#     x              y date      
#     <date>     <dbl> <date>    
#   1 2019-01-02     1 2018-12-30
#   2 2019-01-02     0 2018-12-30
#   3 2019-01-04     1 2018-12-30
#   4 2019-01-04     1 2018-12-30
#   5 2019-01-04     0 2018-12-30
#   6 2019-01-09     1 2019-01-06
#   7 2019-01-19     0 2019-01-13

df %>%
  mutate(x = lubridate::ymd(as.character(x))) %>%
  group_by(date = lubridate::floor_date(x, "1 week")) %>%
  count(name = "count") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  padr::pad(interval = "week",
            start_val = lubridate::ymd("2019-01-01"),
            end_val = lubridate::ymd("2019-02-20")) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) 

# Error: The specified interval is invalid for the datetime variable.
```

It works for day intervals:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(x = lubridate::ymd(as.character(x))) %>%
  group_by(date = lubridate::floor_date(x, "1 day")) %>%
  count(name = "count") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  padr::pad(interval = "day",
            start_val = lubridate::ymd("2019-01-01"),
            end_val = lubridate::ymd("2019-02-20")) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the mismatch between the dates given by `floor_date()` (e.g. 2018/12/30) and the period that you give to `padr::pad()` (e.g. 2019/01/01 to 2019/02/20).

If you change them to be the same then it works.

For example:

```r
    library(lubridate)

    Start_val <- ymd("2019-01-01")
    End_val <- ymd("2019-02-20")

    Adjust_days <- Start_val - floor_date(Start_val, "1 week")

    # Example: Changing floor_date dates

    df %>%
      mutate(x = ymd(as.character(x))) %>%
      group_by(date = floor_date(x, "1 week") + Adjust_days) %>%
      count(name = "count") %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      padr::pad(interval = "1 week",
                start_val = Start_val,
                end_val = End_val) %>% 
      replace(is.na(.), 0)

    #> # A tibble: 8 x 3
    #>   date       name      n
    #>   <date>     <chr> <dbl>
    #> 1 2019-01-01 count     5
    #> 2 2019-01-08 count     1
    #> 3 2019-01-15 count     1
    #> 4 2019-01-22 0         0
    #> 5 2019-01-29 0         0
    #> 6 2019-02-05 0         0
    #> 7 2019-02-12 0         0
    #> 8 2019-02-19 0         0


    # Example: Changing padr dates

    df %>%
      mutate(x = ymd(as.character(x))) %>%
      group_by(date = floor_date(x, "1 week")) %>%
      count(name = "count") %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      padr::pad(interval = "1 week",
                start_val = floor_date(Start_val, "1 week"),
                end_val = floor_date(End_val, "1 week")) %>% 
      replace(is.na(.), 0)

    #> # A tibble: 8 x 3
    #>   date       name      n
    #>   <date>     <chr> <dbl>
    #> 1 2018-12-30 count     5
    #> 2 2019-01-06 count     1
    #> 3 2019-01-13 count     1
    #> 4 2019-01-20 0         0
    #> 5 2019-01-27 0         0
    #> 6 2019-02-03 0         0
    #> 7 2019-02-10 0         0
    #> 8 2019-02-17 0         0
```

Comment: ```start_val = head(.$date,1),
            end_val = tail(.$date,1)```

Comment: Thanks, @Overlytic. I accepted the answer and then thought about it a bit more. Your solution works, but not for the underlying use case. I have a shiny app where the user selects start and end dates that I can pass to `start_val` and `end_val`. It's possible that there are no observations at the start and end of this period, so the `group_by()` with floor can create a padr period that does not include the `start_val` and `end_val`. Changing the padr dates might be the best option. I'm guessing I need to check if the input date is at the floor and subtract days as needed. Thoughts?

Comment: Oh I see. TL;DR. I agree with your suggestion. It depends whether you want your weeks to always start on the same day or not. Also whether you want to show the sum for any partial weeks. Since it is a shiny input I guess you also have an input for the two dates as well as for summarise period (days, weeks, month or year). If you wanted to be truely consistent with the other periods then you should use floor_date(start_val) and floor_date(end_val). Just note that this could show partial sums at the start and the end. But that's probably fine.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect this. But edited it from my mobile. So let me know if it doesn't run.